# how to create CL GL interop context?

Tags: java, opengl, opencl, lwjgl, jocl

For openGL i use lwjgl and for openCL i use jocl.

my video card rx550.

os win10pro.

This my GL Init method, i run it first.

```
static long window;

static void initGL(){
    if(glfwInit()!=true){
        System.err.println("INIT_GLFW_FAILED");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    window=glfwCreateWindow( w, h, "test", 0, 0);
    glfwShowWindow(window);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    GL.createCapabilities();

    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glOrtho(0, w, h, 0, -1, 1);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_3D);

}
```

This my CL init method, i run it second.

```
static void initCL(){
    CL.setExceptionsEnabled(true);

    int numPlatformsArray[] = new int[1];
    clGetPlatformIDs(0, null, numPlatformsArray);
    numPlatforms=numPlatformsArray[0];

    cl_platform_id platforms[] = new cl_platform_id[numPlatforms];
    clGetPlatformIDs(platforms.length, platforms, null);
    cl_platform_id platform = platforms[platformIndex];

    int numDevicesArray[] = new int[1];
    clGetDeviceIDs(platform, deviceType, 0, null, numDevicesArray);
    numDevices = numDevicesArray[0];

    cl_device_id devices[] = new cl_device_id[numDevices];
    clGetDeviceIDs(platform, deviceType, numDevices, devices, null);
    device = devices[deviceIndex];


    cl_context_properties contextProperties = new cl_context_properties();
    contextProperties.addProperty(CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, 
    glfwGetCurrentContext());//wglGetCurrentContext()
    contextProperties.addProperty(CL_WGL_HDC_KHR, wglGetCurrentDC());
    contextProperties.addProperty(CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, platform);

    context = clCreateContextFromType(contextProperties, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 
    null, null, null);

    commandQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device, 0, null);

    mprogram = clCreateProgramWithSource(context,1, new String[]{ program }, null, null);

    clBuildProgram(mprogram, numDevices, devices, null, null, null);

    mkernel = clCreateKernel(mprogram, "sampleKernel", null);

    System.out.println("CLinit done");
}
```

And in this part he say CL_INVALID_GL_SHAREGROUP_REFERENCE_KHR.

```
context = clCreateContextFromType(contextProperties, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, null, null, null);
```

I try change glfwGetCurrentContext() to wglGetCurrentContext() and to window but he say it again.

But if i remove this line

```
contextProperties.addProperty(CL_WGL_HDC_KHR, wglGetCurrentDC());
```

he run perfectly, but if i try to put texture3d

```
clCreateFromGLTexture3D(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_3D, null);
```

he say CL_INVALID_CONTEXT.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using GLFW for your window/WGL context creation, you should make sure to handle your WGL context using GLFW's native wrapper:

http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__native.html

Try setting

```
contextProperties.addProperty(CL_WGL_HDC_KHR, wglGetCurrentDC());
```

to

```
contextProperties.addProperty(CL_WGL_HDC_KHR, glfwGetWGLContext(window));
```

Also make sure that the context is always current when in use.

glfwGetWGLContext is in the GLFWNativeWGL class.